# Google App Script - save to Folder from another Person

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to save Documents into a open folder in Google Drive from another person.

I tried the following code but it doesnt work if i´m not the owner of the  code.

```
function saveToFolder() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###");
  //var destSpreasheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFolderById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).moveTo(folder))
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().
  //get active Sheet
  var sSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive;
  var sheetname = sSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sSheet = sSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  //var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy("test",folder))
  var destSpreadsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(sSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName(), folder)
}
```

The goal is that a lot of people can safe there google sheets to the same folder in google drive by using a button.
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code like [getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive) and using `sSpreadsheet()` instead of `sSpreadsheet` (please refer to the documentation linked). Here is your "fixed code" that takes a Spreadsheet and creates a copy of it in a Drive folder (the code has self-explanatory comments):

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get folder by ID
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");

// Get active Spreadsheet (if this script is not bounded use openById or openByUrl)
  var sSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Make copy
  DriveApp.getFileById(sSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName(), folder)
}
```

Also bare in mind that in order to use [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) you must first [enable the Drive API service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

Comment: Thanks. The script works but I have the problem that if the folder was not created by me, the access is not possible.

Comment: If you want to copy or insert a file into a shared folder (as I assume this is your case) you must have editor level sharing access to that folder.  Were you referring to a shared folder or to a shared drive folder?